# How can I wait for the correct completion of all ongoing processes before the 'driver.quit()' string?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write an autotest that creates an element and then deletes it. Without using 'driver.quit()', everything works. But, if I use 'driver.quit()' then the created element is not deleted. Command 'driver.sleep(5000)' solves the problem and the code fulfills. But the string 'driver.sleep(5000)'is the wrong decision. How can I wait for the correct completion of all ongoing processes before the 'driver.quit()' string?

```
try {
     async function deleteElement(){
         await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("item")), 20000);
         let findItems = await driver.findElements(By.className("item"));
         let items = findItems.map(async elem => await elem.getText());
         await Promise.all(items);
         let currentItem = findItems[findItems.length - 1];
         return currentItem;         
     }
     await driver.get("http://test.com");
     await driver.findElement(By.id("test")).sendKeys('testValue', Key.RETURN);

     await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("item")), 20000);

     currentItem = await deleteElement();
     await currentItem.click();
     currentName = await currentItem.getText();
     await Promise.all(currentName)

     await driver.findElement(By.xpath(
           `//div[div/strong[text()='${currentName}']]//div[@class='delete-icon'][2]`
       )).click();
     console.log("Delete element");

   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e)  
   } finally {
     await driver.sleep(5000)
     await driver.quit();
   }
```

Comment: Can you add implementation of `deleteElement` function? Also why are you awaiting `console.log`?

Comment: @Aleksey, thnx, a add all my code